# Which term came first, "open set" or "open interval"?

Tags: general-topology, math-history

As anyone familiar with toplogy may know, open/closed intervals are closely related with open/closed sets in the standard topology on $\mathbb{R}$. I am interested in the mathematical history behind this: which term came first historically, "open interval" or "open set"?

Comment: Open intervals came first, with the more abstract notion of open set not really being a concept people dealt with until roughly the middle of the 1900-1910 decade (and then only occasionally). Prior to this people talked about being in the interior of an interval, with "open interval" and "closed interval" not being a distinction anyone made (in the late 1800s). Sure, people knew the difference between $(a,b)$ and $[a,b],$ but other than saying "endpoints included" and such, they just used the word "interval". See [this paper](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.hm.2008.01.001) for more.

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro Want to make this an answer? I will accept it if you do so.

Comment: If no one else says anything I'll do this, maybe after checking on a few things first. I wrote that comment quickly as I was heading out the door earlier this morning, and in 5 minutes I have a Skype meeting, after which I have to leave home for 5-6 hours, so it won't be until several hours before I'd have a chance, and I might just wait until tomorrow morning anyway, when I'll be fresher and not as busy.